# How to "batch" create folders for Active Directory users' network drive?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

This is how I add new users to my Active Directory server:

1. Setup the OU's, Groups, etc in AD GUI
2. Create a batch file to create new users (dsmod)
3. Run that .bat file
4. Create a batch file to reset the individual passwords to something unique (admod)
5. Run that .bat file

Now I want to add something to the workflow, which I do not know how:

- Create individual folders in a Local Drive named after each user (e.g. d:\sAMAccount)
- Assign those folders to each respective user in Active Directory
- Automatically Map Network Drive when the users login (assuming their PC's are in the Domain)

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your server side batch:

- create the folder,
- create a share with a sAMAccountName based naming
  convention,
- assign a 'mount my home share' login script to the new    account

  md d:\%sAMAccountName%

  net share home-%sAMAccountName%$=d:\sAMAccountName /GRANT:%sAMAccountName,FULL /REMARK:"Home-Folder for %sAMAccountName%"

  dsquery user -samid %sAMAccountName% | dsmod user -loscr "\SomeDC\NETLOGON\mapHome.cmd"

the 'mapHome' script is the same script for all affected users it just contains:

```
net use h: \\FileServer\home-%USERNAME%$
```